# iOS full texteditor implementation example

Tags: ios, textkit, nstextinput

I want to implement a technical editor and it on macOS i use NSTextInput and Core Text to do all the text stuff myself. But i can't find the NSTextInput equivalent on iOS? Are there examples how to avoid using WebKit or TextKit?

Answer (score 1):

In iOS if you use `UITextView` you can use its delegate i.e `UITextViewDelegate` .I think its what you looking for [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate) is the Apple documentation.

Comment: But this is not helping me if i want to draw the text myself because if have formatting/presentation options not available as text attributes (and unable/too complicated to emulate them).

Comment: @Lothar well you're right. So why do you want to avoid using `TextKit` ? Here are some examples that might help you the first one is using `Texture`:
[VEditorKit](https://github.com/GeekTree0101/VEditorKit) and
[edhita](https://github.com/tnantoka/edhita)